# arrow::open_dataset, hive partitioning, and number-like strings

Tags: r, apache-arrow

Using `open_dataset` with fields that might be numbers but are not fails:

Reprex:

```r
td <- tempfile()
dir.create(td)
dat <- data.frame(fieldA=rep(as.character(1:3), each=3), fieldB=1:9)
for (d in unique(dat$fieldA)) {
  dir.create(file.path(td, paste0("fieldA=", d)), showWarning = FALSE)
  arrow::write_parquet(subset(dat, fieldA==d), file.path(td, paste0("fieldA=", d), "1.pq"))
}
list.files(td, recursive=TRUE)
# [1] "fieldA=1/1.pq" "fieldA=2/1.pq" "fieldA=3/1.pq"
```

If I had instead used `arrow::write_dataset`, the `"fieldA"` would be omitted, which may be the only way I have around this ... but for the sake of the reprex, assume that the partitioning variable is still present in the data.

```r
arrow::open_dataset(file.path(td, "fieldA=1")) |>
  dplyr::collect()
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   fieldA fieldB
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 1           1
# 2 1           2
# 3 1           3
arrow::open_dataset(td) |>
  dplyr::collect()
# Error in arrow::open_dataset(td) : 
#   Type error: Unable to merge: Field fieldA has incompatible types: string vs int32
```

The class of `fieldA` is `character` going into the write, and when one file is read it retains that class. If we write the "normal way" where `fieldA` is omitted in the target parquet file, then it is read in as `integer`.

Because the real data has a number of columns, I would prefer to use the schema already defined in the data, and I don't want to have to define the schema for all columns. If I try to override just one with `schema=arrow::schema(fieldA=arrow::string())` then that's the only column retrieved.

There are times where it is necessary to read in individual files instead of relying on `arrow`'s nice lazy filtering on a connection, so I'd like to be able to read an individual file without losing the partition directory variable (which would happen if I used `write_dataset`).

Am I stuck with removing the partitioning variable from the data? Is there another way to specify the schema for a partition field without having to specify fields' schema?